# Trying to detect a correlation across multiple data sets (same stat, different countries)

Tags: correlation, multiple-comparisons, small-sample

I have two data points, "A" and "B."

A and B are stats the effect countries, so I have data of A and B for four countries, Canada, the UK, the US and Australia.

Due to changes in reporting, each country only has about 5 years worth of valid data.

I know this is an extremely small sample size to perform an independent test on the data points from a single country, but is there any way for me to test each set of data and draw a valid conclusion of correlation if I get the same results over again for each country?

If so which tests would these be?